# Unit Tests for scheduled commands Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, scheduled-tasks

`$schedule->command('abc:some-function {argument}')->monthlyOn(10, '09:00');`

How can I write a unit test for this command ?

Comment: You cannot, and it would also not make sense because you would be testing the framework, not your code... You should test the `command`, not the `schedule`.

Comment: So, how can I trigger it ? @matiaslauriti

Comment: You use a `cronjob`, you don't trigger a `scheduler`. If you want to "trigger" a command (test it), just see [this part of the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/console-tests#introduction), it will help you.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I got it

Comment: @davisria are we actually testing the framework? It is a business requirement to do something on 10th of every month. So don't we need to assert that it is correctly scheduled ?